# Compare Current Day from encode string

Tags: swift, string

I have json response which comes in different languages and I want to compare day; when I choose language Turkish it gets a response like:

```
sunday = {
    day = Pazar;
    timings = (
                    {
            endTime = "23:59:00";
            id = 100000174;
            startTime = "11:58:00";
    }
    );
};
wednesday = {
    day = "\U00e7ar\U015famba";
    timings = (
                    {
            endTime = "22:00:00";
            id = 100000177;
            startTime = "13:00:00";
    }
    );
};

I want to compare them the following way:

if(day.lowercased() == “\U00e7ar\U015famba”) {
    //get Wednesday day
    //this condition work in Sunday Dictionary
}
```

But It shows me error *“Invalid escape sequence”* and *“closure expression is unused”* [Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSmUA.png).

Comment: Did you try to double escape the backslash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, hexadecimal value after the \u escape sequence needs to be enclosed in braces (with the \u as lowercase):

```
"\u{00e7}ar\u{015f}amba"
```

That's the reason for the error you're getting.

However, if you're comparing with the values returned from your JSON, which don't follow this format, you'll need to double-escape the \U to compare them as plain strings:

```
if day.lowercased() == "\\U00e7ar\\U015famba" {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works..may i know how you know this is hexadecimal string ?

Comment: Great, glad to help! The unicode escape \u is always followed by a 4-digit hex string in Swift, but you can also usually tell if there's a cluster of characters formed from the numerals 0-9 and the letters A-F.